# How to get just an element using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get just a visible.

My code is following:

```
import requests
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

IT = requests.get('http://www.pracatobie.pl/employee/FilterAdverts.aspx?oferty=loc@$cat@IT$posall@$')
soupIT = BeautifulSoup(IT.text, 'html.parser')
webIT = soupIT.find_all('div', {'class':'ExtendDataPagerField_div_Record_Count'})
pprint.pprint(webIT)
```

and the out is:
`[<div class="ExtendDataPagerField_div_Record_Count">(z 11269 pozycji)</div>,
 <div class="ExtendDataPagerField_div_Record_Count">(z 11269 pozycji)</div>]`
The only thing that I want is the number (or the text) in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) to extract text and [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) for getting numbers from div's content:

```
def extract_number(text):
    matched = re.match('.[^\d]*(?P<number>[\d]+)', text)
    return matched.group('number') if matched else None

div_elements = soupIT.find_all('div', {'class':'ExtendDataPagerField_div_Record_Count'})
webIT = [extract_number(element.contents) for element in div_elements]
pprint.pprint(webIT)
```

**NOTE**: For better performance [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) your regexp before using it. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but it returned an error.
 File "link.py", line 13, in <module>
    webIT = [extract_number(element.contents) for element in div_elements]
  File "link.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    webIT = [extract_number(element.contents) for element in div_elements]
  File "link.py", line 9, in extract_number
    matched = re.match(r'.[^\d]*(?P<number>[\d]+)', text)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 191, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

Found the way out. Instead of `.find_all()`, I used `.find()` and in `pprint.pprint(webIT)` I added `.get_text()`. So the code looks like this:

```
import requests
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

IT = requests.get('http://www.pracatobie.pl/employee/FilterAdverts.aspx?oferty=loc@$cat@IT$posall@$')
soupIT = BeautifulSoup(IT.text, 'html.parser')
webIT = soupIT.find('div', {'class':'ExtendDataPagerField_div_Record_Count'})
pprint.pprint(webIT.get_text())
```